# Bootstrap 3.2 full-width layout without horizontal scrolling issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I haven't found any proper solution for getting a true full-width or full-page layout for my content using Bootstrap. I tried using the **.container-fluid** class but the padding on the side remains. Removing the padding from the container leads to horizontal scrolling issues, just like many other approaches that I tried.

I set up a fiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/YX4Q8/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <div class="content">
               Content here
           </div>
       ...
```

Comment: Remove the padding on `.col-xs-12` instead of the container.

Comment: Agreed with @entropic see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YX4Q8/1/

Comment: Works indeed, thanks. But my actual problem isn't solved with this. I modified the fiddle. If I nest a row and put two smaller columns in it I get the horizontal scrolling problem I was talking about. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/YX4Q8/2/

Comment: Remove the padding on `.col-md-6` as well then.

Comment: I tried that in the fiddle, the horizontal scroll issue is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/hajey/1/edit

### http://jsbin.com/hajey/1

I would make a special class  for the container and target like that so you don't affect other columns, this is w/o special class.

```
.content {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 200px;
}

.col-xs-12 { padding: 0px }

.container-fluid { padding: 0 }

.container-fluid .row { margin: 0 }

.row .col-md-6 { padding: 0 }

@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .row .col-md-6:first-child { padding-right: 15px }

    .row .col-md-6:last-child { padding-left: 15px }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of changes. What are the consequences if I remove all the paddings and margins? They exist for I reason I assume.

Comment: So I created my own container class like you suggested. Since I only want to lose the padding on small screens I used a media query to apply the properties you listed.

Comment: .row margin has negative left and right margins to accommodate the padding, if you don't have padding, then they won't mess up anything.